# How to import .obj 3D models in ARToolKit instead of .wrl?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .obj, artoolkit, vrml

I'm building an application in ARToolKit for Windows and when I convert my 3D models from .obj to .wrl they lose resolution. I have tried to fix it but I think the problem is the format and not the conversion.

As far as I know, ARToolKit only accepts .wrl models.

¿Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely coming from the conversion because there is nothing in VRML that would imply it's lower resolution than OBJ, it's a very good format :)

Try converting using [AOPT](http://www.x3dom.org/?page_id=532) instead; it's a commandline utility, which is useful for automating:

```
aopt -i from.obj -e to.wrl
```

Comment: It did improve the quality of the model itself, but not when displaying on ARToolKit. That means that the problem is how ARToolKit renders the 3D models. I still need to try other options.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The render quality is so low and the lines of the models are sharp I think the problem is from the openGL setting which is the platform for 3D rendering on ARToolkit